# How do I store and switch over preferences?

Tags: java, enums

I want to store some user preferences  Would Enum be a good datastructure to store them? If so, how do I do it? This is the final usage of the datastructure.

```
main(){
  int my_val = PREFERENCES.BLACK;
  switch(PREFERENCES){

   case BLACK:
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, preferences for a program have a variety of data types: Your windows positions are usually integers expressing X,Y positions; default file or directory names may be strings, color values would usually be stored as `java.awt.Color` values, and so on. `enum`s would come in handy only for values that take on one of a small number of predefined possibilities, and those possibilities aren't values that are naturally represented by integers, characters, strings, floats, colors or other more specialized data types. A good use for an enum would be the position of a toolbar: `{ TOP, LEFT, BOTTOM, RIGHT, CENTER }` or something like that.

Enums are their own data type; you don't store their values in `int`s (or you'd be talking about `final int` fields and not `enum`s). You create some `enum` variables of the type you want, and you can basically only assign one of the type's fixed values to it. You can then later do a `switch` statement on `enum` variables, though.

Answer (score 0):

For a fix set of selectable items, Enum is a good choice. Depending on your application, you could use a [EnumSet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) (at runtime) or some kind of serialization (as persistence) for storing it.

An easy way for serializing Enums is using their numerical value, retrievable by `Enum.ordinal()`